# Object.defineProperty behaves oddly in safari

Tags: javascript, safari

https://jsfiddle.net/smfod698/1/

```
var m = '123'.match(/123/)
alert(m.slice(0))

function Cls() {
    Object.defineProperty(Cls.prototype, "1", {})
}
new Cls()

var m2 = '123'.match(/123/)
alert(m2.slice(0))
```

The first `alert` outputs '123'. After calling `Object.defineProperty`, the 2nd outputs an empty string.

This problem only appears when props name was numeric. eg: `"1"`, `"100"`, until `"4294967294"`.

Is this Safari's bug?

---

P.S.

```
function Cls() {
    Object.defineProperty(Cls.prototype, "1", {})
}
new Cls()
```

these code was from Immutable.js's [Record](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/master/src/Record.js) object

and `'str'.match(/reg/)` was from react-router's [PatternUtils](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/modules/PatternUtils.js)

I use these two libraries, and defined a property with numeric name to a Record, then, I found the react-router can't parse route params correctly.

Comment: Please include the code within your post. Links are welcome for offering additional context, but shouldn't be the sole reference.

Comment: Note: Modifying a constructor's `prototype` from within the constructor is an anti-pattern. A `prototype` is meant for setting shared elements common to all instances while the constructor is for setting instance-specific elements.

Comment: Yes, I would say that's a bug in Safari. `Cls.prototype` or using `Object.definePropert()` with it should have no relation to or effect on an Array created from `.slice()`. (Note: defining the property with `writable: true` seems to avoid the bug.)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski thanks a lot!